# How to fake bluetooth remote control?

Tags: android, python, testing, bluetooth, adb

I'm trying to write some automated tests in Python against a android tv box by using ADB. I've managed to send commands, read logcat, do powercycling and so on by script.

Now I have the problem that after powercycle the box always asks for a BLE-remote control to be available, and if there's none, it asks for pairing. Whats the best way to fake the availability of such a remote control (I have all the specs)? Can it be done by just using ADB? I don't want to have a remote control near the box all the time.